# AttributeError when trying to access 'MediaAudioCapture' on PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView

Tags: python, pyside

I'm encountering an issue when trying to access the 'MediaAudioCapture' property on PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView. The specific error I'm receiving is as follows:

```
AttributeError: type object 'PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView' has no attribute 'MediaAudioCapture'
```

It seems that the 'QWebEngineView' class does not have the 'MediaAudioCapture' attribute. I've reviewed the documentation and available examples, but haven't found a solution to this problem.

Has anyone experienced something similar or have any suggestions on how I can work around this error?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Rafael Ruscher

I attempted to access the 'MediaAudioCapture' property on an object of the 'PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView' class in my Python code. However, in doing so, I encountered the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView' has no attribute 'MediaAudioCapture'
```

My expectation was that the 'QWebEngineView' class would have the 'MediaAudioCapture' attribute, as indicated in the documentation or related examples. I have reviewed the official PySide6 documentation and searched forums, but I haven't found a direct solution to this issue. I would like to understand why this error is occurring and how I can resolve it.

Comment: The `MediaAudioCapture` enum is part of [QWebEnginePage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginepage.html#Feature-enum), not QWebEngineView. Also, since it's an enum, you have to use its full namespace: `QWebEnginePage.Feature.MediaAudioCapture`.

Comment: Working thx! 
QWebEnginePage.Feature.MediaAudioCapture